# Passing an object to Windows Forms EventHandler

Tags: c#

I have searched for hours, but I can't seem to find an answer for this. I feel as if there is a simple answer and I am just banging my head against the wall trying to find it.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ......bunch of code here...

     GroupBoxController GBControl = new GroupBoxController(groupbox1);

}

private void nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     .....I want to be able to access GBControl and modify in here ..........
}
```

Thank you for any answers that might solve this.

Comment: If you want to be able to access `GBControl` from `nextButton_Click` then why do you both declare and assign it ***inside of*** the `Form1_Load`?

Comment: Make `GBControl` a field of the form class, not a local variable of the Load method.

Comment: Scope is your problem here.  Understanding the scope of your variables.  @TGH has fixed the problem by making `GBControl`'s scope more broadly defined, so both methods can access it.

Comment: I need to be able to access GBControl in multiple Events, not just one.

Comment: Well, I was invoking some other methods on it the FormLoad Event.

Answer (score 2):

```
private GroupBoxController GBControl;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ......bunch of code here...

     GBControl = new GroupBoxController(groupbox1);

}

private void nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GBControl.Whatever();
}
```

Try the above.

The general idea is that GBControl is now in scope for all members of the class. Before you had it as a local variable in the Form_Load event handler which makes it inaccessible outside of the function.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!       I had tried something similar by declaring doing something similar to what you had, but I created an instance of the object outside of the Load method. This worked perfectly, much appreciated!